# Is there a way to find list of highly used tags on SO

Tags: support, tags

I am looking to find out what tags are most used on stackoverflow. Is there a way to query this ?

Answer (score 3):

Just go to the Tags tab, https://stackoverflow.com/tags. It is sorted by tag use, most used listed first.

The grey number next to each tag is the number of times it has been used so far:

[image: sample tags listing]

You can change the sorting with the tabs on the top right-hand side:

[image: sorting options]